# SmartGWT into gradle

Tags: web-applications, smartgwt, gradle

I am developing java web-app and I'm using GWT. But I need SmartGWT wrapper over GWT, and I'm using gradle dependency managment. Here is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

configurations { gwtCompile }

dependencies {
             // your own dependencies


             // the gwt servlet dependency for the war file 
    compile     'com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:2.4.0'
    compile     'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.1.1.RELEASE'

             // dependencies for the gwt compiler
    gwtCompile (
        [group: 'com.google.gwt', name: 'gwt-user', version: '2.4.0'],          
        [group: 'com.google.gwt', name: 'gwt-dev', version: '2.4.0']          
    )

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

gwtBuildDir = 'war'

task gwtCompile << {  
    created = (new File(gwtBuildDir)).mkdirs()  
    ant.java(classname:'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler', failOnError: 'true', fork: 'true') 
    {    
        jvmarg(value: '-Xmx184M')    
        arg(line: '-war ' + gwtBuildDir)
        arg(line: '-logLevel INFO')    
        arg(line: '-style PRETTY')    
        arg(value: 'com.trader.TestGWTGradle')    
        classpath {      
            pathElement(location: 'src')      
            pathElement(path: configurations.compile.asPath)      
            pathElement(path: configurations.gwtCompile.asPath)    
        }  
    }
}

war.dependsOn gwtCompile

war {
    baseName = 'TestGWTGradle'
    archiveName = "${baseName}.${extension}"
    from gwtBuildDir 

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'TestGWTGradle Version'
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': '1.0'
        attributes provider: 'gradle'
    }
}
```

Could you give me idea how to do the SmartGWT import here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know gradle, but the same way you've included GWT, and can include SmartGWT. Basically you need to include the two SmartGWT jars (if you want all the skins) :

`smartgwt-skins.jar`
`smartgwt.jar`

You can also retrieve the SmartGWT dependencies from Maven central :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartgwt-skins</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

### edit

following the logic, it would be something like

```
SmartGWTdeps (
    [group: 'com.smartgwt', name: 'smartgwt', version: '2.4.0'],          
    [group: 'com.smartgwt', name: 'smartgwt-skins', version: '2.4.0']          
)
```

Comment: can't you just add your SmartGWT dependencies after the *// dependencies for the gwt compiler* ?